# Question closed because I don't know what commands I can use on this case

Tags: support, closed-questions, windows-10

I have a question about my Super User post being deleted: [Need a command to find and move (and mix) subfolders (and its content) to another subfolder on the same parent folder, all matching specific names](https://superuser.com/questions/1603603/need-a-command-to-find-and-move-and-mix-subfolders-and-its-content-to-anothe)

For what I understand, it's because I haven't tried any command before to solve the task. But as I've commented, I just can't find any similar cuestion. All that I find are relative to move folders/subfolders to other folders/subfolders using "paths", not by finding the specific folders/subfolders by name. And none about forcing to combine/mix those subfolders instead replacing or renaming them.

I would understand if nobody is going to take the time to solve this for me, but any help to guide me trought the correct way will be appreciated and probably it will help other users in the future since seems there is not a similar cuestion nowhere on google (or at least I couldn't find it).

All what I find it's about "moving folders from subfolders to the parent folder"  or "moving subfolders -or its contents- to a single folder" (both using specific paths).

Comment: As you have already been informed https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Comment: We expect you to do some research and try and solve it yourself, then provide the code you have and where you are stuck. If you want it written from scratch then [su] is not the place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

> “I would understand if nobody is going to take the time to solve this for me…”

This site is not a script coding service. All your question does is state what you are trying to do and not showing any examples of what you have done.

The way this site works is if you are trying to do something, have work to show and are stuck, we *might* help you debug your efforts.

But when you post something like this:

> “a bit complex task we have here I guess. I've been searching for a command or program to do it, without success.”

And then have a section that reads:

> “First the scenario:”

Followed by another section that reads:

> “My theorical solutions (notice that I'm a newbye on the commands topic):”

It shows really no effort.

On the Stack Exchange sites you need to show effort of some level. This question you posted shows no level of tangible effort.